# MVC 3 Razor not displaying selected item from dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, displaytag, asenumerable

I have created a form with a dropdown list for 'Region'. Once the form has been submitted I want to be able to view the details from the form. In particular I want the name of the 'Region' to be displayed but I am currently getting the name, ID and labels.

**The dropdown list Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    var db = new AssociateDBEntities();

    var region = db.Regions.Select(r => new { r.RegionId, r.RegionName });
    ViewBag.Regions = new SelectList(region.OrderBy(r => r.RegionName).AsEnumerable(), "RegionId", "RegionName");

    return View();
}
```

**'Details' Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    using (var db = new AssociateDBEntities())
    {
        ViewData["Region"] = new SelectList(db.Regions.ToList(),"RegionName");

        return View(db.Associates.Find(id));
    }
}
```

**'Details' View:**

```
<div class="form-grid-1">
    <div class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Region)</div>
    <div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Region)</div>
</div>
```

How can I just get the name (RegionName) to display?

Comment: You should really look into using view models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Region.RegionName)
```

Or create a DisplayTemplate for Region. Check out
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: I actually just did this!!
I got rid of the `"RegionName"` part in `ViewData["Region"] = new SelectList(db.Regions.ToList(),"RegionName");` in the Controller and used `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Region.RegionName)` and it worked!